# why my power calculation for this resistor is wrong?

Tags: ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws

i encountered a very simple question in a test and i easily calculated the answer
but somehow i am making a mistake because i can not find my answer between the available answers, what am i doing wrong ?
thanks.

**Question :** Calculate the wasted power on the 6 ohm resistor.
[image]

**my current answer using KVL :**
(i*2) - 16 - (4*i) + 4 + (6 * i) - (3 * (4 * i)) = 0
(- 8 * i) = 12
i = -(12 / 8)  A

now power for 6 ohm resistor
p = vi = i^2 * r
p = ((12 / 8) ^ 2) * 6 = 13.5 w

Comment: The dependent current source has a sign inversion that your not taking into account. Your subtracting 3*4*i when you should be adding it.

Comment: @vini_i i am doing the kvl clockwise, when i reach the dependent current source , its from negative to positive , so i say -3V1 , and then i say -3(4 * i) = -12*i, so i am considering the sign. am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXF6dk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the 4 Ω has the voltage signs marked + on the right then let's have current, i, flowing right to left through it and anti-clockwise through the circuit. Starting at R1 and going anti-clockwise we get:

```
4i + 16 + 2i + 12i + 6i - 4 = 0
24i + 12 = 0
i = -12 / 24 = -0.5 A
```

In fact, the current is running clockwise.

Now you have the current you should be able to work out the power in the 6Ω resistor.

I think your problem was falling for the 'trick'. The + and - signs are reversed on the 4Ω resistor. You calculated voltage drop on the 2Ω correctly but did it with the opposite sign on the 4Ω because the question deliberately misled you.

Comment: thx, i got the anti clockwise but i still can't understand why i don't get the answer clockwise!

Comment: starting from R2 resistor , kvl clockwise: i * r2 - 16 - i * r2 + 4 + i * r3 - 12 * i, which part is wrong ?

Comment: i finally understood, because of  + and -, on v1 , i must choose anti clockwise, other wise the resistor delivers which is impossible, Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can actually go clockwise, take note that the signs are reversed, apply the reversal to 3V1 and work out the same result but you have to be consistent. Reversing the current to match the signs given on the 4Ω resistor makes it more natural. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Doing KVL with the current moving clockwise. First there is a positive voltage for +2i. Then 16v voltage is negative. Then the +4i. Then 4V is positive. Then the +6i and finally -3Vi.

Since the Vi for 4 ohm resistor is oppose than the actual voltage then there is sign reversal. So -3Vi turns into 3*4*i.